# Postgres query for digits at the start of an integer column

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, pattern-matching

I'd like to query a series of integer columns which look like this: 10, 1010, 101010, 201010

I want all the ones which start with 10. Changing them to string columns is not an option.

My feeling is that this is potentially achievable using bitstring operators: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-bitstring.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to "change" them to string columns. Just cast for the sake of the test:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  left(int_col::text, 2) = '10';
```

Or, even more succinct:

```
...
WHERE  int_col::text LIKE '10%';
```

That's the appropriate test, too, since your condition is based on the decimal string representation of the number.

Answer (score 1):

This may look stupid, but it may trick the optimiser into using an index (if one is available)

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  int_col = 10
   OR  int_col/10 = 10
   OR  int_col/100 = 10
   OR  int_col/1000 = 10
   OR  int_col/10000 = 10
   OR  int_col/100000 = 10
   OR  int_col/1000000 = 10
   OR  int_col/10000000 = 10
   -- ...
    ;
```

Comment: To use an index (or in any case) use the simpler `int_col = ANY ('{10, 100, 1000, 10000, ...}'::int[])`, which is sargable. On the other hand, if you need this fast, `CREATE INDEX ON tbl (cast(int_col AS text));` and `WHERE int_col::text LIKE '10%'` will be faster. Or even more specialized: `CREATE INDEX ON tbl (left(cast(int_col AS text), 2));` ...

Comment: Could be: I just don't like arrays. Call me oldfashoned if you like, I just HATE arrays.

Comment: Duly noted: arrays are evil. :) How about a list then? `int_col IN (10, 100, 1000, 10000, ...)`. Postgres translates either to `int_col = 10 OR int_col = 100 OR ..` internally.

Comment: Maybe you should add the modulo/div operation to that?